# Is thanking email recommended after a response from author?

Tags: etiquette, email

Suppose I read a research paper and contacted the author for a resource through email. The author responded to the email.

I have no further queries or requests to ask the author.

In such context, **do I need to compose a reply mail** thanking the response provided? Or is it a kind of disturbance for them if I compose mail without any substantial information and just to thank?

Answer (score 6):

You should send it. It assures the original author that you received the email and have no other problems.

Would they be disturbed by it? Probably not, because 1) it's not spam since they're likely to be interested, and 2) it only takes a few seconds for them to process your email.

That said, don't compose a very wordy email - a couple of sentences should suffice.